# In Eclipse I can't get environment variable

Tags: python

**Ubunto 14.04**

I'd like to keep secret info (passwords etc.) in environment variables of Ubuntu. I placed them in user's variables.

**/home/michael/.bashrc**

```
export SECRET_KEY=nh9_j12rx4j_zqiw235_klvm183p5g8bz_s2_fl3auc # Django
```

In terminal I check:

```
michael@michael:~$ echo $SECRET_KEY
nh9_j12rx4j_zqiw235_klvm183p5g8bz_s2_fl3auc
```

In python run under michael:

```
>>> os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
'nh9_j12rx4j_zqiw235_klvm183p5g8bz_s2_fl3auc'
```

Now I run Eclipse IDE and try to get os.environ['SECRET_KEY']. Well, no such environment variable. I think, maybe Eclipse can't access michael's variables even if michael started Eclipse.

Could you help me cope with this problem?

Comment: ... did you really just pasted your **secret** key in an internet post? I hope not. In any case, if that secret key is your actual secret key you **should** immediately change it to something else.

Comment: This is just an example of course not a real key.

Comment: You don't know how many people end up actually doing that. I just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider using `profile` file or `bash_profile` to store the environment variables. You can refer more [here](https://superuser.com/questions/789448/choosing-between-bashrc-profile-bash-profile-etc)

Another approach would be to start Eclipse from an open `terminal` window where you can access the respective environment variable and Eclipse should see them.

Answer (score 2):

Since eclipse does not read your .bashrc, I guess you should specify your environment variables in the context menu where you can set the default interpreter.

Go to Run -> Run Configurations... and Select tab "Environment".

Otherwise, if you want those environment variables available in Eclipse you need to put them in `/etc/environment`.